# How to mock Kotlin attribute get with mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

With

> - Kotlin 1.0.6
> - Mockito 2.6.3

If I have a class like:

```
class UserRepository {
   var loggedInUser: User?
       get() = //...
}
```

How can I mock the get of `loggedInUser` with mockito?

Comment: The question duplicate covers mocking of `final` elements, while this question is about mocking a property. Thus, it shouldn't be closed for that reason.
For that matter, if you apply `open` to the class so Mockito allows you to mock it, you can do `when(mockUserRepository.loggedInUser).thenReturn(someValue)`.

Comment: I marked as duplicate since the other question is related and the answer fix this too.

Comment: @caipivaira Fair enough.